# AngularJS multiple resolve for different APIs but only call the APIs if the user is authorized which is checking another resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authorization, single-page-application, resolve

Look at sample code below, there is authorize function, first item in resolve, the problem is before my authorize function return response the other items like `initData()` and `dashboardData()` will start and try to fetch data, I want `initData()` and `dashboardData()` to start only after my `checkAuthorization()` returns and user is valid. What should I do?

```
$routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
  templateUrl: 'template/dashboard.html',
  controller: 'dashCtrl',
  resolve: {
      authorize: function(authSvc) {
      return authSvc.checkAuthorization();// if authorization fails redirect to login
    },
    initDetail: function(dashSvc) {
      return dashSvc.initData();
    },
    dashboardDetail: function(dashSvc) {
      return dashSvc.dashboardData();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I might be wrong (this _may_ work only with parent-child routes/states) but you can **inject** one resolve into another, e.g. `initDetail: function(dashSvc, authorize){ return dashSvc.initData(authorize); }`. Then simply load the data _if_ you are authorised

Comment: Since the call goes as async the  
    dashSvc.initData(authorize); - 
might already gone before the  authorize return and in this case the injected authorize would be null right? I'm new to angular please correct me if I'm wrong @AlekseySolovey

Comment: You can try reading more about resolves [**here**](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c) (they use `ui.router` instead of `ngRoute`, but they are similar), if you have some kind of check from `authorize` **within** `initDetail` resolve, I think it can process it asynchronously, e.g. `if(authorize.isAuthorized()){return dashSvc.initData(authorize)}`

Comment: Yes, if(authorize.isAuthorized()){return dashSvc.initData(authorize)} I can do this but the problem is I would have to check this in 'initDetail', 'dashboardDetail' and also if there are any items in resolve. So I'll be calling the same 'authorize.isAuthorized()' again and again! I want to call the  'authorize.isAuthorized()' once for a route use it for all the resolve items